# How to handle `env(safe-area-inset-top)` correctly?

Tags: css, environment-variables, iphone-x

I tried the following css to handle the safe area in `Iphone X`. It works fine, but while scrolling back to top, it shows web content under the `status bar`:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 58px;
    background: #fff;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block !important;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    direction: ltr;
    height: 45px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 5px 0 #444;
    z-index: 1040;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
@supports(margin: max(0px)) {
    body {
        margin-top: max(30px, env(safe-area-inset-top));
        margin-bottom: max(15px, env(safe-area-inset-bottom));
    }
}
@supports(top: max(0px)) {
    header {
        top:  max(30px, env(safe-area-inset-top));
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: Did you add `viewport-fit=cover` to the `value` of your `viewport` meta tag?